# Java - Logging into a website in order to retrieve data

Tags: java, authentication, html-parsing, jsoup

What I am attempting to do is: 
Login to a website in order to retrieve data that can only be accessed while logged on.

The website I need to login to is https://www.indemed.com.

I think that this is a two part program, part 1 being logging in, while part 2 is getting the information. When I run the login part of my program and then attempt to manually log in it says my account is in use, which I take to mean it is correctly logging in.

However when I try to get the price it is not there (if not logged in prices will not show up, but everything else will be there).

My questions are: Is there a problem with how I am combining my logging method and my retrieving method? Is the problem just with my logging method? Is the problem with just my retrieving method? Why doesn't this work? Most importantly, how can I fix this?

Here is what I have attempted so far:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class IndependenceMedical {
    public IndependenceMedical(){
        login();
    }
    private void login() {
        URL URLObj;
        URLConnection connect;
        try {
            // Establish a URL and open a connection to it. Set it to output mode.
            URLObj = new URL("https://www.indemed.com/Action/Login/LoginAction.cfm?Refer=/index.cfm");
            connect = URLObj.openConnection();
            System.out.println(connect.toString());
            connect.setDoOutput(true);

            // Create a buffered writer to the URLConnection's output stream and write our forms parameters.
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(connect.getOutputStream()));

            writer.write("AccountNumber=12345&UserName=myUserName&Password=myPassword&Login=Login");
            writer.close();
            // Now establish a buffered reader to read the URLConnection's input stream.
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connect.getInputStream()));
            String lineRead = "";
            // Read all available lines of data from the URL and print them to screen.
            while ((lineRead = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(lineRead);
            }
            reader.close();
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            System.out.println("The URL specified was unable to be parsed or uses an invalid protocol. Please try again.");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage() + "\nAn exception occurred.");
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    public Document getDoc(String itemNumber){
        try {
            return Jsoup.connect("https://www.indemed.com/Catalog/SearchResults.cfm?source=advancedSearch&psku=" + itemNumber + "&keyword=&PHCPCS=&PClassID=&ManufacturerID=&Search.x=41&Search.y=9").get();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {}
            return null;
        }
    public String getPrice(Document doc){
        try{
            Elements stuff = doc.select("#tr_51187955");
            stuff = stuff.select("div.product-price");
            String newStuff = stuff.toString();
            newStuff = newStuff.substring(newStuff.indexOf("$")); // throws exception because "$" is not in the String.
            newStuff = newStuff.substring(0, newStuff.indexOf(" "));
            return newStuff;
        }
        catch (Exception arg0){
            return "";
        }
    }



    public static void main(String[] args){
        IndependenceMedical test = new IndependenceMedical();
        Document doc = test.getDoc("187955");
        System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n"); //to separate the return lines
        System.out.println(test.getPrice(doc));
    }
}
```

Due to character restrictions and the fact that I don't know which parts are important, I can't show the output. However if requested I will try to provide all the requested output.

Sorry for being so wordy I'm just trying to make sure the question is clear.

Lastly I have thoroughly looked through other login questions and although there are examples of how to login, I can't seem to find how to do anything after logging in (i'm sure someone has talked about it, but I haven't been able to find it).

Thanks in advance to anyone that can help me with this.

**EDIT:**

Although this question is similar to [Parse HTML source after login with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7741694/parse-html-source-after-login-with-java)

I'm not parsing the redirected page, I need access to all pages this grants access to.

Comment: Do you understand how that site expects the session token to be returned? When you login to a site the login page usually sets an encrypted cookie that you must send on every subsequent request.  You read the response data but didn't do anything with it.

Comment: @JimGarrison Honestly I know < 0 with internet interactions in java. this is the first time i've ever needed to do anything more than just parse a page.

Comment: In that case you need to do some studying on how HTTP works and how web sites encode login information from one request to the next. You have a lot of fundamental learning to do before you can write this type of code, and unfortunately SO is not a handholding or tutorial site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jsoup provides the methods for login mechanisms. 
Try the below, after you've filled the username, password and account number.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.util.Map;

import org.jsoup.Connection;
import org.jsoup.Connection.Method;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class IndependenceMedical {

    private Map<String, String> loginCookies;

    public IndependenceMedical() {
        login();
    }

    private void login() {
        try {
            Connection.Response res = Jsoup.connect("https://www.indemed.com/Action/Login/LoginAction.cfm?refer=MyAccount&qs=")
                    .data("UserName",       "myUserName")
                    .data("Password",       "myPassword")
                    .data("AccountNumber",  "myAccountNumber")
                    .method(Method.POST)
                    .execute();

            loginCookies = res.cookies();
        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            System.out.println("The URL specified was unable to be parsed or uses an invalid protocol. Please try again.");
            System.exit(1);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage() + "\nAn exception occurred.");
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    public Document getDoc(String itemNumber){
        try {
            return Jsoup.connect("https://www.indemed.com/Catalog/SearchResults.cfm?source=advancedSearch&psku=" + itemNumber + "&keyword=&PHCPCS=&PClassID=&ManufacturerID=&Search.x=41&Search.y=9")
                        .cookies(loginCookies)
                        .get();

        } catch (IOException e) {}

        return null;
    }

    public String getPrice(Document doc){
        try {
            Elements stuff = doc.select("#tr_51187955");
            stuff = stuff.select("div.product-price");
            String newStuff = stuff.toString();
            newStuff = newStuff.substring(newStuff.indexOf("$")); // throws exception because "$" is not in the String.
            newStuff = newStuff.substring(0, newStuff.indexOf(" "));
            return newStuff;
        } catch (Exception arg0) {
            return "";
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        IndependenceMedical test = new IndependenceMedical();
        Document doc = test.getDoc("187955");
        System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n"); //to separate the return lines
        System.out.println(test.getPrice(doc));
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry if this is like REALLY basic, but how would I know what the session ID is?

Comment: Updated the cookies section to not bother with the session id name

Comment: When I run the code and just print out what is returned from `doc.select("#tr_51187955")` (before narrowing it down further) in `getPrice` it prints the html as if it didn't login.

Comment: Try printing the loginCookies map. Check if it contains the session id.

Comment: when printing the map it prints: {CFTOKEN=(randomNumbers), CFID=(randomNumbers)} so I believe that works fine.

Comment: <td width="150" valign="top"> <span class="soldby">Sold by: BX of 10 EA</span><br /> This is part of what prints when I print my partially parsed code. Looking at the web site:    [item link](https://www.indemed.com/Catalog/SearchResults.cfm?source=advancedSearch&psku=187955&keyword=&PHCPCS=&PClassID=&ManufacturerID=&Search.x=41&Search.y=9)    When logged in the price is right above "Sold by: BX of 10 EA" which when I look at the code in my web browser it says the price in between the  "top"> and the <span class="soldby"

Comment: Although anything is possible I have parsed other websites (which didn't need a login) using this method with no problems, and I see no reason as to why logging in would change this process.

Comment: Not the process, just the selector. Like this one doc.select("#tr_51187955"); It seems a little random. Maybe it's content that is being generated by javascript. If that is the case then jsoup can't handle it.

Comment: Oh, well the the number can be explained, 187955 is the item number, and the 51 before that is the company number (the one that makes the item). So it isn't random there is a reason for all the numbers.

Comment: Also when I inspect element, I can see the price in the code, so I don't believe it is being generated in a way that it can't be read with Jsoup.

Comment: Does the server expect a certain value for element btnSubmit?

Comment: Although I don't see that there is a specific value needed, it may be important to note that in the frmLogin there is an onsubmit="return _CF_checkfrmLogin(this)" which may require a response.

Comment: That js function is just for the ui. Nothing important.

Comment: Check my update. The url for posting the login data was not the right one.

Comment: Thank you so much for being so patient and having such a deep understanding of this material :) it works beautifully.

Comment: Thank you for your kind words. I'm glad I could help.